# How to create a custom control to resemble an electronic breadboard using WPF?

Tags: wpf, expression-blend

A breadboard is a tool that is used to implement simple electronic circuits, it is a set of nodes used to put ICs on them and connect between them using wires to build the circuit.
[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadboard)

What I want to do is to make a user control in WPF to be used in a larger application that simulates electronic circuits.

The user has to place ICs on that breadboard.

The first approach I used is to make the user control with a background image of a breadboard, inside it is a layout container ex: StackPanel (To stack ICs horizontally) with height that covers the central part of the image.

and then I made another user control that resembles an IC to be added to the former container, I drew the pins and a black rectangle.

Specifically what I want to do now is to make the size of the IC relative to that of the breadboard. meaning that when the size of the breadboard expands or shrinks the IC will remain in the same points it was.

This is the XAML code of the Breadboard:

```
<UserControl
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Breadboard"
mc:Ignorable="d"
x:Class="Breadboard.MainControl"
x:Name="UserControl" d:DesignWidth="91.583" Width="Auto" d:DesignHeight="26.501" Padding="0">
<UserControl.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/breadboard.png" Stretch="Uniform"/>
</UserControl.Background>

<StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" Height="8.835">
    <StackPanel.Background>
        <ImageBrush/>
    </StackPanel.Background>
    <local:IC Margin="0" Width="Auto"/>
</StackPanel>
```

This is the XAML code of the IC:

```
<Viewbox Stretch="Fill">

    <StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" Height="40" Width="52.833">
        <StackPanel x:Name="UpperPins" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="Images/pin.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="7" Margin="3,0,0,0"/>
            <Image Source="Images/pin.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="7" Margin="6,0,0,0"/>
            <Image Source="Images/pin.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="7" Margin="6,0,0,0"/>
            <Image Source="Images/pin.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="7" Margin="6,0,3,0"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <Rectangle Fill="Black" Height="36"/>
        <StackPanel x:Name="LowerPins" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Horizontal" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="180"/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </StackPanel.RenderTransform>
            <Image Source="Images/pin.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="7" Margin="3,0,0,0"/>
            <Image Source="Images/pin.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="7" Margin="6,0,0,0"/>
            <Image Source="Images/pin.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="7" Margin="6,0,0,0"/>
            <Image Source="Images/pin.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="7" Margin="6,0,3,0"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Viewbox>
```

This is the C# code of the IC (The Constructor):

```
namespace Breadboard{
public partial class IC : UserControl
{
    public IC(int pins)
    {
        if (pins % 2 != 0) throw new OddNumberOfPins();
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Width = (pins/2)*(6 + 7);
        UpperPins.Children.Clear();
        LowerPins.Children.Clear();
        UpperPins.Children.Add(new Image() { Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Images/pin.png",UriKind.Relative)), Stretch = Stretch.Fill, Width = 7, Margin = new Thickness(3, 0, 0, 0) });
        LowerPins.Children.Add(new Image() { Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Images/pin.png", UriKind.Relative)), Stretch = Stretch.Fill, Width = 7, Margin = new Thickness(3, 0, 0, 0) });

        for (int i = 0; i < (pins/2)-2; i++)
        {
            UpperPins.Children.Add(new Image() { Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Images/pin.png", UriKind.Relative)), Stretch = Stretch.Fill, Width = 7, Margin = new Thickness(6, 0, 0, 0) });
            LowerPins.Children.Add(new Image() { Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Images/pin.png", UriKind.Relative)), Stretch = Stretch.Fill, Width = 7, Margin = new Thickness(6, 0, 0, 0) });

        }
        UpperPins.Children.Add(new Image() { Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Images/pin.png", UriKind.Relative)), Stretch = Stretch.Fill, Width = 7, Margin = new Thickness(6, 0, 3, 0) });
        LowerPins.Children.Add(new Image() { Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Images/pin.png", UriKind.Relative)), Stretch = Stretch.Fill, Width = 7, Margin = new Thickness(6, 0, 3, 0) });


    }

    public IC():this(6)
    {

    }
}

public class OddNumberOfPins : Exception
{
    public OddNumberOfPins()
    {
       //TODO
    }
}
}
```

I'm using Expression Blend to do the XAML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a grid, with columns and rows equal to the number of pin holes.
Place empty columns/rows to account for empty columns/rows in the real device.

In each grid cell add a grid.
In the inner grids create a 3x3 row/column layout.
For the first and last row/column, create * Gridlengths so you can adjust relative sizes between the buffer area and the middle cell.

In the middle cell of the inner grids, add a rectangle with an ellipse using a drawing brush (so again, it stays relative).

Here's XAML with the first row filled in.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication5.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="579" Width="274">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}" x:Key="PinHole">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
                                <Rectangle.Fill>
                                    <DrawingBrush>
                                        <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                                            <GeometryDrawing Brush="Black">
                                                <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                                    <GeometryGroup>
                                                        <EllipseGeometry Center="1,1" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1"/>
                                                        <EllipseGeometry Center="1,1" RadiusX=".5" RadiusY=".5"/>
                                                    </GeometryGroup>
                                                </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                            </GeometryDrawing>
                                        </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                                    </DrawingBrush>
                                </Rectangle.Fill>
                            </Rectangle>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <UserControl Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=PinHole}"/>
        <UserControl Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=PinHole}"/>
        <UserControl Grid.Column="3" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=PinHole}"/>
        <UserControl Grid.Column="4" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=PinHole}"/>
        <UserControl Grid.Column="5" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=PinHole}"/>
        <UserControl Grid.Column="6" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=PinHole}"/>
        <UserControl Grid.Column="7" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=PinHole}"/>
        <UserControl Grid.Column="9" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=PinHole}"/>
        <UserControl Grid.Column="10" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=PinHole}"/>
        <UserControl Grid.Column="11" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=PinHole}"/>
        <UserControl Grid.Column="12" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=PinHole}"/>
        <UserControl Grid.Column="13" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=PinHole}"/>
        <UserControl Grid.Column="15" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=PinHole}"/>
        <UserControl Grid.Column="16" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=PinHole}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Now, when you add ICs, split them up into visual parts (top-left corner, etc), and arrange the parts in the right grid cell locations, together as a unit.

In code, you can have an IC unit that you give a top-left cell to, and then the parts of the IC will set their Grid.Row and Grid.Column to the right locations.

Comment: Thank you, but this has to do with the shape of the breadboard itself, I think I can achieve the same effect with any layout with a background image of the breadboard like this [one](http://i.imgur.com/wELgj.jpg)
But this has nothing to do with the real problem I am facing right now. As I said above I want to make the size of the IC relative to that of the breadboard. meaning that when the size of the breadboard expands or shrinks the IC will remain in the same points it was.

Comment: I've added a StackPanel inside the main grid to stack ICs vertically and it works and the width of the ICs (rectangles) inside that StackPanel keeps relevant to the size of breadboard but its height is not because I had to specify it exactly not auto. So how can I make the height relevant to the size of the breadboard as the width.
I've also thought of putting the ICs directly on the main grid, but I couldn't access the cells directly.

Comment: @IslamMoustafa I forgot to add what to do about the ICs. Check the answer now.

Comment: Thank you so much, but can you give me an example with code because I don't know what do you mean by a "visual part" is in WPF

Comment: I'm did it by adding Rectangles to the grid and setting their Grid.Row and Grid.Column and determining their width and height by setting Grid.ColumnSpan and Grid.RowSpan, but still you know the it doesn't look like a real IC, so can you advice me on the best way to implement it to look like a real IC with all the pins and stuff. I thought of inheriting the Rectangle class but it is sealed.

Comment: You'll have to get creative with the drawing brush. That's what will let your parts scale

Answer (score 0):

Move the Viewbox that you currently have in your IC XAML up to surround the Breadboard's root StackPanel. Once you do that you can used fixed sizing on everything inside the Breadboard and set the desired relative size on the IC also as a fixed size and the Viewbox will handle all the scaling for you, keeping all the internal relative sizing of your controls intact.

Comment: Ok, I don't think that this approach will be valid in multiple ICs Scenario.

Comment: What do you think the problem would be with multiple child controls?

Comment: May be I didn't understand your answer that much, because when the ViewBox of that one IC surround that of the breadboard's, what will happen when a new IC id added..!?
Can you please provide any example..

Comment: The Viewbox doesn't belong to the IC. I was recommending removing it from IC and putting it around the parent control instead so it would be structured like: <Breadboard><Viewbox><StackPanel><IC/><IC/><IC/></StackPanel></Viewbox></Breadboard>